# Can I compute the decoding of QR code using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to decode QR code using Python,I have installed libraries like Pillow and Pyzbar. This is my code:

```py
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('C:/Users/Danat/Documents/all my works/holidays/project/python related practice project/myqrcode1.png')

result = decode(img)
print(result)
```

But it shows the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\Danat\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pyzbar\libzbar-64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

What should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=FileNotFoundError%3A+Could+not+find+module+%28or+one+of+its+dependencies%29.+Try+using+the+full+path+with+constructor+syntax.